# How can I get the foreground element for a specific day?

Tags: fullcalendar

Is there a way to get a reference to the foreground cells containing the event divs? the `dayRender` event seems to only provide reference to the background cell.

I would like to list additional non-event data on a date without it being covered up by events, or truncated.

My first attempt used `dayRender` but that goes through dates multiple times (all-day cell at the top vs regular cell below). I actually only want the all-day cells.

Now I'm using `viewSkeletonRender` and `let $day = $(info.el).find('.fc-day[data-date="' + date + '"]').eq(0)`.

There doesn't seem to be enough info on the foreground cells to select them in a similar manner.

EDIT: My current implementation using `viewSkeletonRender` had issues so I used `datesRender` instead, however all my custom DOM gets destroyed upon any re-rendering the calendar does. So I'm back to using `dayRender` with a similar technique to what I've mentioned above.

And here's what I am trying to accomplish (employee shift hours listed in the all-day cells, rather than as actual events within the calendar, which is for appointments):

[image]

Comment: eventRender will get you each individual event (it executes once per event, just as dayRender executes once per day). But what do you want to do with the event elements when you've got them, exactly?

Comment: I'm trying to do something like this, where an employee's shift is listed at the top rather than as an actual event within the calendar. 

EDIT: Oops, couldn't paste image here. I'll add it to the question, instead.

Comment: How are you delivering the shift data? Via an event source feed? Or some other way?

Comment: I was hoping to fetch every shift in the view using `datesRender` but currently grab all the shifts for the current day being rendered in `dayRender`. So it's not provided to the calendar, I'm just fetching and inserting into the DOM. I'm thinking I should provide it as an event source where there's one artificial all-day event per day, and I show all the shifts in the one event, and remove styling from it. Then I can use the `eventRender`and not worry about messing with the DOM

Comment: I ended up doing what I described in my previous comment, and created an answer for my question with detail on how that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than try to add this extra shift information directly into the DOM using callbacks, I ended up creating an event source fed by an events function which grabs the employee shifts, groups them by day, and then returns a single all-day event for each day.

I was able to make these events look how I wanted by setting the background and border colors to `inherit` setting `editable` to `false`, and using `eventRender` to set the HTML (or remove the element entirely if in a view where I didn't want to display shifts).

Here's the event source and event-generating function:

```
{
    id: 'staff-hrs',
    events: async (info, success, failure) => {
        let {shifts} = await ScheduleAPI.get_shifts_in_date_range(info.start, info.end)

        // generate HTML for each shift and group by date
        let dates = {}

        shifts.forEach((shift) => {
            let time = `${shift.start} - ${shift.end}`
            let name = `${shift.first_name} ${shift.last_name}`

            if (shift.start == '00:00:00' && shift.end == '00:00:00') {
                time = 'All-day'
            }

            let $div = $('<div />')
            let $time = $('<strong />').html(time)
            let $name = $('<span />').html(name)

            if (shift.date in dates === false) {
                dates[shift.date] = []
            }

            dates[shift.date].push(
                $div.append($time ,' ', $name)
            )
        })

        // generate an all-day event for each date, with reference to the HTML els
        let events = []

        for (let date in dates) {
            events.push({
                id: `${date}-shifts`,
                start: `${date}T00:00:00`,
                allDay: true,
                editable: false,
                html: dates[date]
            })
        }

        return events
    },
    backgroundColor: 'inherit',
    borderColor: 'transparent'
}
```

Here's the event render callback function

```
function handle_eventRender(info) {
    if (info.event.extendedProps.html) {
        if (info.view.type == 'listWeek' || info.view.type == 'dayGridMonth') {
            $(info.el).remove()
        } else {
            $(info.el).html(info.event.extendedProps.html)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ADyson thanks. To anyone who might come across this there's one annoyance to how this works. In the event render callback, removing the event element when it's not desired isn't perfect because the other events on the same day will be positioned as if the removed event is still present in the DOM. I ended up making a simplified `title` property for my event objects, and that gets used instead of me removing the element.